# Two masses connected by two pulleys with one of the masses on an incline

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, kinematics

> What are the accelerations of the masses?
> For mass one, summing the force in both directions
> $$\sum F_x= m_1g\sin(\theta)-T=m_1a$$
> $$\sum F_y=F_n-m_1g\cos(\theta)=0$$

So the acceleration is for mass one is $a=g\sin(\theta)-\frac{T}{m_1}$, which is the same for $m_2$.
Is this correct?

[image]

Comment: Hi there, and welcome. What is your exact question here? Is there a reason that you would doubt your approach since you are asking to check-your-work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for questions similar to that in the OP and in general for dynamical modeling, executing an analysis which considers the geometry, kinematics and dynamics in that order is a good strategy.

In the figure provided, if we denote the distance of the fixed pulley from the material particle model of $m_2$ by $l_2$ and similarly the distance of $m_1$ the fixed pulley from $m_1$ by $l_1$ then the geometric relationship of the two lengths is $l_1+2l_2=constant$ so that on differentiating this equation, we have the kinematic relationship $v_1=-2v_2$ and $a_1=-2a_2$.

The dynamical equations given in the OP are accurate and we use their notation to write the dynamics for $m_2$ as $2T-m_2g=m_2a_2$ or $a_2=\frac{2T}{m_2}-g$ so that $a_1:=a=2a_2=g\sin\theta-\frac{T}{m_1}=\frac{4T}{m_2}-2g$ so that $T=\frac{m_1m_2}{4m_1+m_2}(2+\sin\theta)g$ and $a=g\sin\theta-\frac{T}{m_1}$ provide the required acceleration after doing some algebra.

Answer (score 0):

if you take a closer look here you'll notice something really interesting.
See, when you raise mass m2 by 'x' units both segments of the string around the pulley are loosened by 'x' units so m1 travels a total of '2x' units along the incline. So,
X(m1)=2 * X(m2)  (where X(m1) and X(m2) are displacements of m1 and m2 respectively.)
Now if we differentiate both sides with respect to time we get,
V(m1)=2 * V(m2) (where V(m1) and V(m2) are velocities of m1 and m2 respectively)
Now if we differentiate both sides with respect to time one more time we get,
a(m1)=2 * a(m2) (where a(m1) and a(m2) are accelerations of m1 and m2 respectively)

So we can say that acceleration of m1 is twice acceleration of m2.

By the way if you write the force equations for both masses and add them the tension (T) term will be cancelled off leaving you with a beautiful answer.